# Xamarin.Android, SfChart, Widget

Tags: charts, xamarin.android, widget, syncfusion, drawingcache

I have SfChart where part is on C# and xml. There is anyway to put this inside of widget?
Maybe anyway to transfer whole object into widget or export to bitmap (getDrawingCache and DrawingCache are deprecated). Have anyone idea with sample?

Edit: converted to Bitmap working but only on live View(on screen). When trying only in cs. Bitmap is black. On Android.Forms was Platform.CreateRenderer(view) but on Xamarin.android nothing i found.

Answer (score 0):

Greetings from Syncfusion.

Currently, we don’t have support to update the SfChart in Android widget without rendering in the UI. We have already logged a feature request for this requirement, and you can track the feature using the feedback link below.

Feedback: https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/19685

Regards,
Devakumar D

Comment: Thank You for answer, yes but this is slowing down option for main ui. Maybe there is some way te draw it? I can create hidden things but it's lew less professional.